# Garbage character while running old program in windows xp/7

Tags: windows, unicode, character-encoding, foxpro

I have an old bill creation program written in foxpro 2.6.0.The program works fine in windows 98.But when used in windows xp,a particular window displays garbage/incorrect characters for english character and for numeric values.In windows 7 numeric values are correct,but characters are still invalid..Please help to resolve the same.The problem seems to be due to some character encoding which is present in windows 98 but not in windows xp/7.

Thanks.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a font issue to me. Your old program is probably trying to use FoxFont and it's probably not installed on your new machine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have searched the net,but didnt find any appropriate link to download and install the same.Could you please tell me the source from where i can get the required font

Comment: Look on your Windows 98 machine. This font came with older versions of FoxPro.

Comment: Thanks Tamar.I have installed Foxpro 2.6.0 for windows and with that foxfont are also installed and my problem is solved.